# Getting 403 forbidden on all xml files on my server

Tags: xml, apache-2.2

I recently moved a site to a new server where the server configuration is not allowing access to xml files:

```
[error] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/website/test.xml
```

After further testing, I get a 403 (forbidden) when trying to load any xml files.
How do I enable server xml files in apache? I'm assuming it's an apache configuration.

Thanks!

Solution:
my .htaccess had:

```
<Files ~ "\.(xml)$">
    deny from all
</Files>
```

I removed the above htaccess directive and denied only the xml files that shouldn't be accessed directly.

Comment: You are getting this only for XML files? Are you 100% sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Apache `Allow`/`Deny` directives are configured to forbid access to the file you're trying to get.

These directives will likely be in your `<VirtualHost>` configuration, or an `.htaccess` file.  Please edit your question with this info and we can assist in straightening out the rules.

Comment: <Directory /website>
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

Comment: It was being disallowed in the .htaccess file. Thanks!

Comment: <Files ~ "\.(xml)$">
deny from all
</Files>

Answer (score 1):

you'll generally get that type error when directory permissions are wrong, do all your xml files happen to be in the same directory?

1. check the permissions on the XML files,
2. see if you can load another type [html] file from that directory
3. see if you can load an xml file from another directory or site.

I have a feeling it is file permissions [did you move the site VIA shell or an archive?]

-sean

Comment: It's not a permission issue. I can change the extension to .js and it loads up as plaintext in the browser. I set permissions to 666 just to be sure.
same thing happens with new files. (not moved from the old server).